# vbnet save picture box image drawings on it

Tags: vb.net

ım trying to do is draw a text on PictureBox and then merge picture box image with text and save it
my code

```
     Dim g As Graphics = PictureBox2.CreateGraphics

        g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
        g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
        g = PictureBox2.CreateGraphics
        Dim myfont As Font = New Font("Courier New", 17, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim pnt As Point = New Point(149, 272)
        Dim Text As String = "A4Q9-A11P-55G9-REFR" 'TextBox1.Text
        g.DrawString(Text, myfont, Brushes.Black, pnt.X - 3, pnt.Y)
        PictureBox2.Image.Save("test.png")
```

ı try with Bitmap but still same no text in test.png

Comment: If you're calling `CreateGraphics` then you've already lost. I suggest that you check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684) out. It shows how to draw temporarily on a `PictureBox` and then transfer that to permanently on an `Image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim bmp As Bitmap = PictureBox2.Image
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
Dim myfont As Font = New Font("Courier New", 17, FontStyle.Bold) 
Dim pnt As Point = New Point(149, 272)
Dim Text As String = "A4Q9-A11P-55G9-REFR" 
g.DrawString(Text, myfont, Brushes.Black, pnt.X - 3, pnt.Y)
bmp.Save("test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```